# Why is font not displaying accurate in Brackets?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I installed 'Brackets' and i saw that the font is not displaying accurate..
I'm using `'Brackets 1.13'` 
my **problem** is very clear in this picture..
[image: Brackets font are not displaying accurate]

Currently i am using `'Deepin 15.7'` 
I have already used 'Brackets' in 'Ubuntu', 'Linux mint' and faced same problem with them and... 
 
Please go to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088861/why-does-brackets-sidebar-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-18-10

and answer this question too .